# Replace an installed program with a newer version

Tags: linux, installation, debian, updates, apt

I have GCC 4.6 on my Raspbian installation, but I'd like to use GCC 4.9.
I can of course do `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9` but then I have to use `gcc-4.9` in order to use the newer version of GCC. I can also change to what `gcc` links to, but GCC isn't the only program i'm having this problem with, and I'm not sure if wouldn't have to change more stuff in order to fully replace GCC 4.6. So, what can I do?

another program I'm having this problem with is Python (3.2 vs 3.4)

Comment: Can you not just do `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade gcc` to update to the latest version?

Comment: @Stretch nope it's still the same version. Note that gcc-4.9 is different package

Comment: What about [update-alternatives](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/update-alternatives.8.html)?

Comment: If gcc-4.9 is in the repository you should really install it using `apt-get upgrade`! Updating gcc is a complicated (and somewhat dangerous) process, as it changes quite a lot of libraries and executables. If gcc-4.9 is _not_ in the repository, and you want to compile and install, then it is more complicated. You should be *very* careful. Even so, you should use `apt-get` to remove the original package. Python 3.2 vs 3.4 is less dangerous, but still complicated. Any module packages you installed in 3.2 will have to be re-installed. The `apt-get upgrade` is still your best tool.